# Cannot read from proc_open to cs2cs process stream(s) unless I close the stdin stream first

Tags: php, proj

I am trying to use the proj program in my PHP project to convert (project) projected transverse-mercator coordinates (X/Y) on a flat map into lat/long coordinates. For this purpose, I spawn the proj program (cs2cs in this case) using the projection parameters and then input the X/Y coordinates into the STDIN pipe of the program and read the calculated lat/long coordinates from the STDOUT pipe. I will convert a lot of coordinates, so a lot of STDIN/STDOUT communication will happen, which is why I am using proc_open to accomplish this.

When trying to do this, I run into a problem: In order to read the converted coordinates from STDOUT, I first have to close (fclose) the STDIN pipe, otherwise the read from STDOUT will hang forever. But if I do close the STDIN pipe, then this only works for one conversion and the second conversion will fail because the STDIN pipe is already closed and cannot be used to send more XY points to the program.

```
<?php

$pipes = [];

$process = proc_open(
    '/usr/bin/cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=neu +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=33 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=-99516.999999973 +y_0=-4998115 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +vunits=m +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs +axis=neu', 
    [["pipe", "r"], ["pipe", "w"], ["pipe", "w"]], 
    $pipes
);

fwrite($pipes[0], "-278904 723829\n");
fclose($pipes[0]); # If this fclose line IS commented out, the fgets directly below this line will hang forever.
var_dump(fgets($pipes[1]));

fwrite($pipes[0], "-278904 723829\n"); # If the fclose is NOT commented out, this will fail: not a valid stream resource
var_dump(fgets($pipes[1]));

echo "done.";
```

With the fclose in place:

```
$ php proc.php 
/home/gerrit/test/proc.php:13:
string(36) "42d11'23.632"N  42d57'59.643"E 0.000
"
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: fwrite(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /home/gerrit/test/proc.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 /home/gerrit/test/proc.php(15): fwrite()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/gerrit/test/proc.php on line 15
```

With the fclose commented out I do not get any output because it hangs at the first fgets call.

I have already checked STDERR for any error messages, but there are none. (The STDERR either also blocks without the fclose, or returns an empty string after "fclose($pipes[0])" was called).

How can I accomplish proper back and forth communication between PHP and proj/cs2cs ?

I have also tried to create a test script that interacts with bash instead of cs2cs, but that script worked fine. Is this maybe some kind of problem with cs2cs?

Versions:

```
$ php --version
PHP 8.1.16 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:34:53) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.16, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans

$ dpkg -l | grep proj-bin
ii  proj-bin                                      6.3.1-1                                                      amd64        Cartographic projection library (tools)

$ uname -a
Linux gerrit 5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS \n \l
```